# SED or something to delete everything after first space up to `|`

Tags: command-line, text-processing, stat

I have a little bash snippet I'm working on:

```
$ stat --printf=%A\|%U\|%G\|%s\|%y\|%N'\n' /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-124/zfs/cmd/zhack
drwxr-xr-x|root|root|4096|2018-05-17 05:54:49.361904361 -0600|'/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-124/zfs/cmd/zhack
```

The date is rather ugly so I'd like to use `sed` (or whatever works) to delete everything after the first space up to the following `|`. Of course if the `stat` command can print the date normally that works too!

Any tips for the `sed` challenged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With `bash`

```bsh
$ a=$(stat -c'%A|%U|%G|%s|%y|%N' /etc/profile) ; echo ${a/ *|/|}
-rw-r--r--|root|root|575|2017-09-22|'/etc/profile'
```

This is [`bash`’s Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace), more precisely Pattern Substitution, see [`man bash`/EXPANSION/Parameter Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13). I also took the freedom to simplify your command line a bit.

#### With `awk`

```bsh
$ stat -c'%A|%U|%G|%s|%y|%N' /etc/profile | awk -v{O,}FS=\| '{sub(/ [^|]+/,"",$5)}1'
-rw-r--r--|root|root|575|2017-09-22|'/etc/profile'
```

This is slightly longer, but actually the most accurate solution: It changes explicitly the fifth field *only* so that spaces in file and user names ([expect the unexpected](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2008/08/13/on-valid-unix-usernames-and-ones-sanity)) won’t be a problem. Compare:

```bsh
$ a="-rw-r--r--|ro ot|ro ot|575|2017-09-22 17:35:19.337510248 +0200|'/etc/pro fi|le'"
$ sed 's/ [^|]*//' <<<$a
-rw-r--r--|ro|ro ot|575|2017-09-22 17:35:19.337510248 +0200|'/etc/pro fi|le'
$ echo ${a/ *|/|}
-rw-r--r--|ro|le'
$ awk -v{O,}FS=\| '{sub(/ [^|]+/,"",$5)}1' <<<$a
-rw-r--r--|ro ot|ro ot|575|2017-09-22|'/etc/pro fi|le'
```

The username should not contain a bar `|` though – however, you could take care of that eventuality as well:

```bsh
$ b=$(awk -F\| '{print NF-1}' <<<"ro||ot") # how many bars again?
$ a="-rw-r--r--|ro||ot|ro||ot|575|2017-09-22 17:35:19.337510248 +0200|'/etc/pro fi|le'"
$ awk -v{O,}FS=\| '{sub(/ [^|]+/,"",$'$((5+b*2))')}1' <<<$a
-rw-r--r--|ro||ot|ro||ot|575|2017-09-22|'/etc/pro fi|le'
```

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```bsh
$ stat --printf='%A|%U|%G|%s|%y|%N\n' /etc/profile | sed 's/ [^|]*//'
-rw-r--r--|root|root|575|2015-10-23|'/etc/profile'
```

Which simply replaces a space followed by non-`|` characters with nothing.

Comment: "simply" is in the hands of the coder :). Looks good. The file name could have a space but is unlikely to have a pipe character in it so I think I'm good now. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix both cases do not matter, since `|` will always come between the date (which also always includes a space) and the filename using the format you have given.

Comment: Yup. Script is finished now. Coming to a screen soon near you. I'll put in a credit note for your sage sed help.